# Where can I find a list of what traits do?

Tags: dragon-quest-monsters-joker-2

I'm playing through Dragon Quest Monsters: Joker 2 and I've got a lot of monsters but I don't have a clear understanding of what their traits do. Where can I find a list showing the effects of the various traits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Ngirl_GF's FAQ [here](http://m.gamefaqs.com/ds/987442-dragon-quest-monsters-joker-2/faqs/63292).

See the "traits" section.

Comment: This is another really nice site I found after googling a bit: http://www.woodus.com/den/games/dqm5ds/traits.php